# ngModel not working inside form Tag

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material, multi-select

***[(ngModel)] not working inside form Tag***

When I am using Multi Select Outside Form tag is working fine to select All  and 
Deselect All  Function

But i when i put inside  Form it working Selecting All Values

```
<form [formGroup]="roleForm">

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-select placeholder="Select Role Type" formControlName="roleType" (selectionChange)="roleTypeSelect($event.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roleTypeList" [value]="role.roleTypeId">
                {{role.roleTypeName}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field> <!-- Multi Select Mat Start -->
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">

        <mat-select placeholder="Select Privileges" class="filter-select" [formControl]="selectedItems" [compareWith]="equals" multiple
         #privilegeSelect="ngModel">
            <mat-option disabled="disabled" class="filter-option">
                <button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary fill text-sm" (click)="selectAll(privilegeSelect, dropdownList)">
                    Select All
                </button>
                <button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary fill text-sm eta-margin-all" (click)="deselectAll(privilegeSelect)">
                    Deselect All
                </button>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let privilege of dropdownList" [value]="privilege">{{privilege.itemName}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>

    </mat-form-field>
    <!-- Multi select mat end -->

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna Rathore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ngModel` becouse you are using `formControlName`.

I have create a demo on **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-not-working-inside-form-tag?file=app/select-multiple-example.html)**

> **component.ts**

```
roleForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
      toppings: [null]
    })
}

toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];

selectAll() {
    this.roleForm.get('toppings').patchValue(['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'])
}
deselectAll() {
    this.roleForm.get('toppings').patchValue([])
}
```

> **component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="roleForm">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">

        <mat-select  placeholder="Select Privileges" class="filter-select" formControlName="toppings" multiple>
            <mat-option disabled="disabled" class="filter-option">
                <button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary fill text-sm" (click)="selectAll()">
                    Select All
                </button>
                <button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary fill text-sm eta-margin-all" (click)="deselectAll()">
                    Deselect All
                </button>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let privilege of toppingList" [value]="privilege">{{privilege}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>

    </mat-form-field>

<p>Selected Value--{{roleForm.get('toppings').value}}</p>

</form>
```

Comment: I have object of Json as List  so how i can apply use PatchValue for that  please tell me

Comment: {id: 1, itemName: "Login 1"}
{id: 2, itemName: "Configuration"}
{id: 3, itemName: "Organization"}
{id: 4, itemName: "User Management "}
{id: 5, itemName: "Notification Management"}
{id: 6, itemName: "Functions"}

Comment: Yes Its working Perfectly fine , I have one More Question

Comment: DO you have any demo for file upload in material design

Comment: I don't have any demo of Material File upload. let me create and i will update you.

Answer (score 10):

If you just use `ngModel` without a surrounding `<form>`, you don't have to specify a `name` for the input.

```
<input ... [(ngModel)]="model.something"`>
```

**But when you do use it in a form, the `name` attribute becomes mandatory !**

```
<form>
  <input ... name="something" [(ngModel)]="model.something"`>
</form>
```

It's actually in the docs:

> When using the ngModel within  tags, you'll also need to supply a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent form under that name.

If you miss it, it won't show any errors at all, it just won't work.